# How to add NSArray dynamically to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios

hello Every One i have list of arrays that i want to store in single mutable array how to do this please help here what i am doing to short out the problem

```
NSMutableArray *cityContainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
city1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"abc",@"deg",@"fog",nil];
city2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"mathura ",@"aagra ",@"delhi",nil];
city3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"jammu",@"chhata",@"barsana",nil];


   for (int i = 1; i < 4 ; i++)
{
    [cityContainer addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"city%d",i]];
}
```

Now the Problem is that its storing array Names only like city1,city2,city3. i don know why my data is not storing in mutable array please help

Comment: Are you looking for `addObjectsFromArray:` method of mutable array?

Comment: No i do not think that i am looking for that method. If question is not clear to you please let me know so i can describe it more Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your three arrays as you currently have, then create your mutable array in a single statement rather than a `for` loop.

```
NSMutableArray *cityContainer = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:city1, city2, city3, nil];
```

The name of a variable as a string of characters isn't the same thing as the variable itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your Comment Phillip. But my problem is that i have 100-200 City array if i will do that the same way you mention its not dynamic it will be static way although . Can it is possible via loop any How ??

Comment: How are you actually creating your city arrays?  You show them each being assigned as static variables, is it different in real code?  Do you need the individual variables or can you use something like: `[cityContainer addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc", @"deg", @"fog", nil]]` as you create them?

Comment: yes these are different in real code basically what i am doing is that suppose i have 1 array in witch 5 country`s are stored if i select first county mean 0 index so i want to show array of cityContainer`s 0 index is that make sense

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question and include code that matches what you're really doing.  It's hard to answer a question about one situation when the example describes a different situation.

Comment: Ok thanks well now i am doing my task as you suggested